# ExactTarget API Account permissions

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a question around this API account that we create on Code.ExactTarget.com

The various permissions that we configure here - how these work with the permissions of the Marketing Cloud user that this API account is linked with ?

Which one is more restrictive?